# What do painkillers do?

Tags: dead-pixels

What do painkillers do? I've used them a few times, and I haven't noticed anything happen at all, except for getting the painkillers icon in the left corner of the screen which obviously means they should have some kind of effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They make you take half damage while they're in effect